# Error when generating database from model in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I have installed VS2013 but still have VS2012. In VS2013 I cannot generate a database from a model in Entity Framework. I get the following error message:

[image]

The files in the error message do exist!
Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Seems similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664833/metadata-file-not-found-data-entity-model. Can you tell me what your system drive is? (I am trying to figure out how to reproduce this...)

Answer (score 1):

Your tip about checking the drive made me see what I should have seen before. 
The environment variable VS120COMNTOOLS had the wrong drive letter. Can't remember, but I initially installed VS2013 on another drive and then changed it back to C. Anyway setting it correctly fixed the problem.
/Peter

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve this. A colleague on our team tried to repro this but was not able to which is inline with your response.

Answer (score 0):

I believe VS is not updating the `VS120COMNTOOLS` variable correctly when reinstalling VS to a different drive. See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867641/entity-framework-in-visual-studio-2013-library-not-found/19912856#19912856) for an extended answer.