# MS OData Client Code Generator fails : Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'Microsoft.OData.Client.dll' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, t4

After pulling a project from source control down to a new dev machine with VS 2013 I found I could no longer generate my Client side proxy and entity classes (from the .tt file created by "OData Client Code Generator")

I get exceptions compiling the transform with

- Microsoft.OData.Client.dll
- Microsoft.OData.Core.dll
- Microsoft.OData.Edm.dll

e.g.

```
Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'Microsoft.OData.Client.dll' could not be found
```

Followed by a few hundred other build errors as the tt file failed ot generate the required classes giving instead only the dreaded

```
ErrorGeneratingOutput
```

This is despite these dlls and their accompanying xml files being present in the correct place in the project Bin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I realised that **I had not installed the relevant bits from "Extensions and Updates"**

1. Tools > Extensions and Updates
2. Online > Visual Studio Gallery > "OData Client Code Generator" (type / paste into search)
3. Installed Version 2.3.0

**Bam -** all working again and generating my proxy and entities correctly !

Silly me.

Comment: If I could up vote this more I would. I'm really mystified what about the T4 template requires the OData Client Code Generator extension to be installed in Visual Studio.

Comment: @MHollis thanks, and yes I agree it's really not obvious but I guess it must be that something (or more than one thing) referenced from the relevant .ttinclude is missing without the extension installed.

Comment: According to [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867641/entity-framework-in-visual-studio-2013-library-not-found/19912856#19912856) some VS internals require those DLL's separately... Check the comment by Pawel.

Comment: Seriously! I think I spent half a day looking for this :|