# Entity Framework throws error generating output

Tags: entity-framework

I have used entity framework 5(ef5) with ado .net entity model for backend purposes. I just changed the project to ef 6 and i build the project it works fine .Now when i update a table using update from table datamodel.context.cs file and datamodel.tt  everything related to entity shows error genearting output

I have also checked the packages installed Ef6.01 and EF 6.02 are installed .

I have surfed the net too .Couldnt get any solution .Can anyone please suggest some solution

Comment: Could you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be related to my following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896856/upgrade-from-entity-framework-5-to-6/21899100#21899100)

Here, the problem was that the T4 templates were still from version 5