# Update Model from Database reverts manual changes made to .context file

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

we recently updated from EF4 to EF6, then I read about .context.tt and .tt files. Added them to the system things look fine but

> System.Data.Object

was to be changed to

> System.Data.Entity.Core.Object

I thought this would be one time effort but everytime we update model from database, we have to rename the namespaces, its not difficult but annoying.

Did we miss something while upgrading to EF6 or are we using .context.tt files in wrong way ?

Comment: Maybe you are still pointing at old templates? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896856/upgrade-from-entity-framework-5-to-6

Comment: oh Man, thanks for pointing me in this direction.. I was still ! please move your comment to answer .. I will edit with my changes and accept that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templates were upgraded to use the new namespaces, but you may need to manually update them. See this link  [Upgrade from Entity Framework 5 to 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896856/upgrade-from-entity-framework-5-to-6)