# Changing Code generation from T4 to Legacy objectContext causes exceptions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I created a new model :

1. ADO.NET Entity Data Model
2. EF Designer from database .

When I changed the `Code generation` from `T4` to `Legacy objectContext`

I got :

> The type or namespace name 'EntityClient' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Data'
>
> The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Data'
>
> The type or namespace name 'EdmSchemaAttribute' could not be found

Any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: What version of EntityFramework is in use?

Comment: @LSU.Net : `package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add the EF 6.0 DbContext Generator, as your current template is generating EF 5.0 code. See @boindil's answer.

> I think your problem is, that your T4 templates, which generate the
>   entitties and the context are still in EF version 5.
>
> First you have to delete the current code generation items, which are
>   in the code behind of the model, namely .Context.tt and
>   .tt.Next add a new EF version 6 code generator with Right
>   click in the model designer-> Add Code Generation Item ... -> EF 6.x
>   DbContext Generator.

[Upgrade from Entity Framework 5 to 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896856/upgrade-from-entity-framework-5-to-6)

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the namespaces to

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;
```