# EntityFrameworks.dll file missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am totally new to the .NET world and been trying to build an MVC application following [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application) tutorial, creating a database first then creating an MVC project on top of it and whenever I create the Models from the existing db I get a number of errors like this:

> Error 1 Compiling transformation: Metadata file
>   '%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\EntityFramework.dll' could not be
>   found c:\users\j\desktop\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\ContosoSite\ContosoSite\Models\ContosoModel.tt

And this one also:

> Error 2   Compiling transformation: Metadata file
>   '%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll' could not be
>   found c:\users\j\desktop\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\ContosoSite\ContosoSite\Models\ContosoModel.tt

I have Entity Frameworks installed (version 6.1)

after hours of googling and searching for answers apparently there is a(or many) file(s) missing (dll?) in my Windows 8.1 OS.

Has anyone come up with a solution for this?

J

Comment: Did you find this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664833/metadata-file-not-found-data-entity-model

Comment: Just install through nuggets , google command install

Comment: @meda what do you mean by install through nuggets? is it the dll file?

Comment: `Install-Package EntityFramework` run that in the package manager console

Comment: @rene that post was bang on, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Followed the steps as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664833/metadata-file-not-found-data-entity-model) stackoverflow, rebuilt the Models from the db and voila! All Sorted

Credit to @Jaon

1. Check your install location. I installed VS to the other location D:\ than default C:\ so I got the error.
2. modify "Environment Variables" to your location, for me it means changing  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\ to D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools.
3. DON'T Forget to add a \ to the end of word.

Comment: How do you get to Environment Variables?

Comment: * Open Windows explorer
* Right click on "This PC/My Computer"
* From the context menu select "Properties" 
* In the opened windows Click "Advanced System Properties"

Comment: I have the same issue in VS 2019, but I don't have any System Variable relative to it

Answer (score 2):

The project in the example uses the help of a library called "Entity Framework" to help with database queries. In Visual Studio these libraries are installed as Nuget Packages. For more info about Nugets, check this [link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/overview)

In order to install this library follow these steps in your Visual Studio IDE.
Go to Tools>Package Manager Console>Package Manager Console.
When the console opens up, type "Install-Package EntityFramework" and hit enter key.
This will install Entity Framework Nuget Package to your IDE. Then you can use this library by adding a using reference.

Comment: I have EF 6.1 installed in my project (I just amended my question, apologies if this was not clear)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with VS2019. I shared my experience [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57735996/6363853).

> The file that needs to be edited is in the
>   “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework
>   Tools\Templates\Includes” directory. The file you want to edit
>   (assuming you are using EF6 and C#) is called
>   EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude. If you edit that file and replace
>   “$(VSAPPIDDIR)EntityFramework.dll” with the full path to
>   “…\Common7\IDE\EntityFramework.dll” (and similarly for the other
>   reference to VSAPPIDDIR) then you should be good to go.

Comment: File is locked or read-only when I try to edit. (Visual Studio is shut down).

Comment: Save a copy in your desktop and replace it with original file. Try changing file attributes or start your windows in safe mode.