# EntityFramework.dll missing?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I installed VS Express Web, I installed EntityFramework 6.0 tools and I added the EntityFramework using NuGet. All of this is reasonably fresh and I get the following error when I try to create an ADO model:

Error   2   Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 13.0\Common7\Tools..\IDE\EntityFramework.dll' could not be found

I've looked in the above folder and within Common7 I have an "IDE" folder but I don't have a "Tools" folder. Is there something I needed to install that I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867641/entity-framework-in-visual-studio-2013-library-not-found/19912856#19912856

Comment: Tried that but it didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 1):

I know thar your problem is solved, but, after 3 days searching, mine solved using [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/619754/view.html). I hope it would be useful for others by saving at least 3 days.

> The file that needs to be edited is in the
>   “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework
>   Tools\Templates\Includes” directory. The file you want to edit
>   (assuming you are using EF6 and C#) is called
>   EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude. If you edit that file and replace
>   “$(VSAPPIDDIR)EntityFramework.dll” with the full path to
>   “…\Common7\IDE\EntityFramework.dll” (and similarly for the other
>   reference to VSAPPIDDIR) then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you can uninstall Entity Framework (EF) 6.0 and install EF 5.0, to see if its an issue with the installation.

Or could you go a version up and try installing EF 6.1?

Hopefully that may help with at identifying where the issue lies.

Comment: Thanks for the help, not exactly sure what fixed it, I did a bunch of things including the things you suggested and one of them in the list got it working :)

Comment: Good to hear. If you could narrow down what you did and choose a accepted answer it could help other users who view your post